# Thread and Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have come across this statement that to create a new thread it is best to use the `Runnable` interface instead of extending the `Thread` class. If that is true, why does Java even allow us to extend the `Thread` class. Why not make it `final`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the thing you are making is almost certainly not a thread. It's a `ThingTheDoesSomeUsefulWork` and you happen to want it to do that useful work on a separate thread. Let's say I'm writing a thing which polls a web server every 30 seconds. Is `ThingThatPollsWebServer` a thread? Or is it just a thing that polls a web server.

Besides, making a `Runnable` makes it easier to test, plus it gives you the flexibility to run your thing without using a thread, or using the executor framework.

Comment: How does this answer my question. You only seem to advocate the Runnable interface. What about extending Thread?

Comment: Yes, because it's the right thing to do! Only extend Thread if you want to specialise its behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change the behaviour of a thread or add additional functionality. If this is the case, then extending the Thread class is most suitable.

Comment: Exactly. The cited statement isn't unconditionally true, so accepting it as truth and then wondering why the `Thread` class design doesn't follow it is a little misguided.

Comment: You're right. But how often you see `Thread`'s being subclassed not to solely implement `run`?

Comment: btw, what should I do if I want to change behavior of `Class` or `String`? No, sir. That's bad logic.

Answer (score -2):

Using Threads was the old way (before java 5.0) of using, well Threads :). Take a look at the class ExecutorService.